# Bootstrap collapse - go to top of the open item?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, scrollto

I'm using the bootstrap collapse function, but when I open an element which has a lot of content, then open the next element, it jumps down and doesn't go to the top of the open element. I've tried using scrollto plugin as shown below but it doesn't work:

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $('a.accordion-toggle').click(function(){
        $.scrollTo( this, 500);                                             
    })
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
    <div class="accordion-group heading-left-11">
        <h5 class="accordion-heading row">
            <a class="accordion-toggle span11" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapse1">Austria</a>
            <div class="icon-rt span1">
                <span class="icn"></span>
            </div>
        </h5>
        <ul id="collapse1" class="member_list accordion-body collapse row">
            <li class="accordion-inner pull-left span4">
                <a href="http://www.cidinet.eu/display_distributor.php?id_target_distributor=101">Filmladen</a>
                <span> Michael Stejskal</span><a href="http://www.cidinet.eu/display_distributor.php?id_target_distributor=101" title="Filmladen" ><img src="http://dev.europa-distribution.org/assets/logos_film_laden-570x190.png" alt="Filmladen" ></a>
            </li>
            <li class="accordion-inner pull-left span4">
                 <a href="http://www.cidinet.eu/display_distributor.php?id_target_distributor=194">Polyfilm</a>
                 <span> Hans Koenig</span><a href="http://www.cidinet.eu/display_distributor.php?id_target_distributor=194" title="Polyfilm" ><img src="http://dev.europa-distribution.org/assets/logos_polyfilm-570x190.png" alt="Polyfilm" ></a>
             </li>
             <li class="accordion-inner pull-left span4">
                 <a href="http://www.cidinet.eu/display_distributor.php?id_target_distributor=228">Stadtkino Filmverleih</a>
                 <span> Claus Philipp</span><a href="http://www.cidinet.eu/display_distributor.php?id_target_distributor=228" title="Stadtkino Filmverleih" ><img src="http://dev.europa-distribution.org/assets/logos_stadtkino_filmverleih-570x190.png" alt="Stadtkino Filmverleih" ></a>
             </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-group heading-left-11">
        <h5 class="accordion-heading row">
            <a class="accordion-toggle span11" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapse2">Belgium</a>
            <div class="icon-rt span1">
                <span class="icn"></span>
            </div>
        </h5>
        <ul id="collapse2" class="member_list accordion-body collapse row">
            <li class="accordion-inner pull-left span4"><a href="http://www.cidinet.eu/display_distributor.php?id_target_distributor=6">ABC</a><span> Nicolaine Den Breejen</span><a href="http://www.cidinet.eu/display_distributor.php?id_target_distributor=6" title="ABC" ><img src="http://dev.europa-distribution.org/assets/logos_genci_kino_abc-570x190.png" alt="Genci kino abc" ></a></li>
            <li class="accordion-inner pull-left span4"><a href="http://www.cidinet.eu/display_distributor.php?id_target_distributor=61">Cineart-Cinelibre</a><span> Eliane du Bois &amp; Stephan de Potter</span><a href="http://www.cidinet.eu/display_distributor.php?id_target_distributor=61" title="Cineart-Cinelibre" ><img src="http://dev.europa-distribution.org/assets/logos_cineart-570x190.png" alt="Cineart" ></a></li>
            <li class="accordion-inner pull-left span4"><a href="http://www.cidinet.eu/display_distributor.php?id_target_distributor=127">Imagine Film Distribution</a><span> Christian Thomas &amp; Tinne Bral</span><a href="http://www.cidinet.eu/display_distributor.php?id_target_distributor=127" title="Imagine Film Distribution" ><img src="http://dev.europa-distribution.org/assets/logos_imagine-570x190.png" alt="Imagine" ></a></li>
            <li class="accordion-inner pull-left span4"><a href="http://www.cidinet.eu/display_distributor.php?id_target_distributor=214">Le Parc Distribution</a><span> Jean-Pierre Pécasse</span><a href="http://www.cidinet.eu/display_distributor.php?id_target_distributor=214" title="Le Parc Distribution" ><img src="http://dev.europa-distribution.org/assets/logos_le_parc-570x190.png" alt="le Parc distribution" ></a></li>
            <li class="accordion-inner pull-left span4"><a href="http://www.cidinet.eu/display_distributor.php?id_target_distributor=145">Lumière</a><span> Jan de Clerq &amp; Annemie Degryse</span><a href="http://www.cidinet.eu/display_distributor.php?id_target_distributor=145" title="Lumière" ><img src="http://dev.europa-distribution.org/assets/logos_lumiere-570x190.png" alt="logos_lumiere" ></a></li>
            <li class="accordion-inner pull-left span4"><a href="http://www.cidinet.eu/display_distributor.php?id_target_distributor=383">O’Brother</a><span> Olivier Bronckart</span><a href="http://www.cidinet.eu/display_distributor.php?id_target_distributor=383" title="O’Brother" ><img src="http://dev.europa-distribution.org/assets/logos_obrother_distribution-570x190.png" alt="obrother distribution" ></a></li>
            <li class="accordion-inner pull-left span4"><a href="http://www.cidinet.eu/display_distributor.php?id_target_distributor=185">Paradiso Filmed Entertainment</a><span> Olivier Mortagne</span><a href="http://www.cidinet.eu/display_distributor.php?id_target_distributor=185" title="Paradiso Filmed Entertainment" ><img src="http://dev.europa-distribution.org/assets/logos_paradiso-570x190.png" alt="Paradiso Films" ></a></li>
            <li class="accordion-inner pull-left span4"><a href="http://www.cidinet.eu/display_distributor.php?id_target_distributor=529">U-Dream</a><span> Stephanie Van den Berge</span><a href="http://www.cidinet.eu/display_distributor.php?id_target_distributor=529" title="U-Dream" ><img src="http://dev.europa-distribution.org/assets/logos_udream-570x190.png" alt="uDream" ></a></li>                                
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-group heading-left-11">
        <h5 class="accordion-heading row">
            <a class="accordion-toggle span11" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapse3">Bulgaria</a>
            <div class="icon-rt span1">
                <span class="icn"></span>
            </div>
        </h5>
        <ul id="collapse3" class="member_list accordion-body collapse row">
            <li class="accordion-inner pull-left span4"><a href="http://www.cidinet.eu/display_distributor.php?id_target_distributor=337">Artfest</a><span> Stefan Kitanov &amp; Mira Staleva</span><a href="http://www.cidinet.eu/display_distributor.php?id_target_distributor=337" title="Artfest" ><img src="http://dev.europa-distribution.org/assets/logos_artfest-570x190.png" alt="Art Fest" ></a></li>
            <li class="accordion-inner pull-left span4"><a href="http://www.cidinet.eu/display_distributor.php?id_target_distributor=302">Pro Films</a><span> Emil Simeonov</span><a href="http://www.cidinet.eu/display_distributor.php?id_target_distributor=302" title="Pro Films" ><img src="http://dev.europa-distribution.org/assets/logos_pro_films-570x190.png" alt="Pro Films" ></a></li>                                     
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-group heading-left-11">
        <h5 class="accordion-heading row">
            <a class="accordion-toggle span11" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapse4">Canada</a>
            <div class="icon-rt span1">
                <span class="icn"></span>
            </div>
        </h5>
    <ul id="collapse4" class="member_list accordion-body collapse row">
        <li class="accordion-inner pull-left span4">Metropole Films<span> Charles Tremblay</span><img src="http://dev.europa-distribution.org/assets/logos_metropole_film_distribution-570x190.png" alt="métropole Films Distribution" ></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have scrollto working with bootstrap collapse but the code is for WordPress. I brought in your content and it works. Bootstrap Collapse has a shown event and then you need to know the height of the content to scroll up.

```
$(".accordion-body").on("shown", function () {
    var selected = $(this);
    var collapseh = $(".collapse .in").height();
    $.scrollTo(selected, 500, {
        offset: -(collapseh)
    });
});
```

You may need to tweak it a bit but it should work.

Comment: did anyone has freezing/flickering effect when your try to scroll using mouse after the animation has ended?

Answer (score 12):

The event name has changed in Bootstrap 3, so @bboymaanu's won't work as shown. It should use the 'shown.bs.collapse' event instead.

```
$(".accordion-body").on("shown.bs.collapse", function () {
    var selected = $(this);
    var collapseh = $(".collapse.in").height();
    $.scrollTo(selected, 500, {
        offset: -(collapseh)
    });
});
```

The new events are [documented here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse).

Answer (score 6):

```
$(".accordion-body").on("shown", function () {
var id = $(this).attr('id');
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#'+id).offset().top + -50}, 1000);
});
});
```

Simple Example. The ".top + -50" is Minus 50px from the top of the element allowing some padding at the top.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution built on others suggestions which:

- also works for embedded accordians
- scrolls so the header is also shown
- only if not already on screen
- animates as well

Code:

```
$('#accordion').on('shown.bs.collapse', function (e) {

  // Validate this panel belongs to this accordian, and not an embedded one
  var actualAccordianId = $('a[href="#' + $(e.target).attr('id') + '"').data('parent');
  var targetAccordianId = '#' + $(this).attr('id');
  if (actualAccordianId !== targetAccordianId) return;

  var clickedHeader = $(this).find('.panel > .collapse.in').closest('.panel').find('.panel-heading');
  var offset = clickedHeader.offset();
  var top = $(window).scrollTop();
  if(offset) {
    var topOfHeader = offset.top;
    if(topOfHeader < top) {
      $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: topOfHeader}, 100, 'swing');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: The fourth line needs to be:
`var actualAccordianId = $('a[href="#' + $(e.target).attr('id') + '"]').data('parent');`

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#accordion').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {

  var panel = $(this).find('.in');

  $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: panel.offset().top
  }, 500);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

I used the following, works like a charm:

```
$("#accordion2").bind('shown', function() {
        var active=$("#accordion_univlist .in").attr('id');
        scrollhere('#'+active);
        $('.closebutton-right').hide(); 
}); 

$('.accordion-heading').click(function () { 
  // Do something if you want to do on click  else ignore this handler.
}

function scrollhere(destination){
    var stop = $(destination).offset().top - 80;
    var delay = 1000;
    $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: stop}, delay);
    return false;
}
```

It also gives a bounce effect, and I like it.